# Calculus: calculate the limit $ (1+\frac 1 {n^2})^{n^3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

I am doing my homework in calculus and I got this problem that I got to find the limit for  $(1+1/n^2)^{n^3}$ as n goes to infinity.
I can rewrite the expression as $((1+1/n^2)^{n^2})^n$ but from what I know I can't take the limit inside the () before I take the limit of the outside exponent (in which case I would get e^n which goes to infinity).

Can anyone explain to me how I can calculate the limit rigorously?

Comment: It does tend to infinity: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hyzw88kzq8

Comment: Honestly, I can't tell where the exponents should be.  Do you mean $(1+\frac{1}{n^2})^{n^3}$?  Or $((1+\frac{1}{n^2})^n)^3$?  (Not that it matters much on the final verdict...)

Comment: You could rewrite it how you you had intended then use logs to bring the outermost n down from there it's much easier

Comment: Please verify that my edits capture what you intended to ask...

Comment: @abiessu Yes, thank you

Comment: @Corali93 If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: @gimusi How do I set it as solved? Can't find it..

Comment: @Corali93 http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Successive applications of [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), $(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx$, reveals

$$\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)^{n^3}\ge \left(1+\frac{n}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}\ge \left(1+\frac{n^2}{n^2}\right)^n=2^n$$

Comment: Mark.$(1+x)^k \ge 1+kx.$ or $(1+1/n^2)^{n^3} \ge 1+ n.$

Comment: @PeterSzilas And what is the issue?  I was using successive applications to arrive at a tighter lower bound.

Comment: Sure, if you want tighter bounds, ok. If you want to show divergence only, the above line does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: there exists $\;N\in\Bbb N\;$ such that

$$n>N\implies 2\le\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)^{n^2}\le3\implies2^n\le\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)^{n^3}\le3^n$$

and now apply the squeeze theorem...

Comment: Thank you very much! This was a great solution

Comment: You don't really need to squeeze, the lower bound is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)^{n^2}=e,$$we have$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)^{n^2}\right)^n=+\infty$$and therefore your limit is $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\ln(1+1/n^{2})^{n^{3}}&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^{3}\ln(1+1/n^{2})\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{n^{3}}}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}}\dfrac{-2}{n^{3}}\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{-3}{n^{4}}}\\
&=\infty,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{n^{3}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\exp\left(\ln\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{n^{3}}\right)=\infty.
\end{align*}